# Unable to install gimp (Unmet dependency)

Tags: gimp

I am trying to install GIMP on an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install. Unfortunately, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.10.18) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.10.18-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.4-0 (>= 0.4.22) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks, I really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: If you're helping to test the development release (*focal fossa* isn't 20.04 until release time), then you can also use #ubuntu-quality via IRC or telegram, however general support should still go to #ubuntu+1 sites until *focal fossa* has been released and reached stable 20.04).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y  && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: i had a similar issue, and solved it by using aptitude (which had to be installed): `sudo aptitude install libgegl-0.4-0`. I did not accept the first solution (basically, do nothing), but the second solution was to install a newer version with some deps. I accepted it and was then able to install Gimp, although it's still listed as upgradable.